# I want to add this type of table in my documentation, what will be the latex code of this table?

Tags: latex, documentation, tabular

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Compare with SAT-based approach}
\label{Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     Assay & Baseline &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Our strategy} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{SAT based Approach}\\
     \cline{2-3} \cline{3-5} \cline{5-7}
             & time-steps (T) & \#$CP$ & $CP/T * 100$ & \#$CP$ & $CP/T * 100$  \\
      \hline
      Text 1 & Text 3         & Text 5 & Text 7       & hjhb   & hjhbh   \\
      \hline
      Text 2 & Text 4 & Text 6 & Text 8 & hjhb & hjhbh \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

I am trying to create few column with multiple column.

Above code is for this table:

[image: Above code is for this table]

but here I marke some line which I don't want and some line don't apper in the table. Please anyone help on it.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 6 columns in your table, but you draw a line from column 5-7. Replace this line

```
\cline{2-3} \cline{3-5} \cline{5-7}
```

with

```
\cline{1-2} \cline{2-4} \cline{4-6}
```

Comment: `\cline{1-6}` would be equivalent to your line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

My sketch for this table:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5px}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Compare with SAT-based approach}
\label{Results}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Assay} & Baseline & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Our strategy} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{SAT based Approach}\\
\cline{2-6}
 & time-steps (T) & \#$CP$ & $CP/T * 100$ & \#$CP$ & $CP/T * 100$\\
\hline
Text 1 & Text 3 & Text 5 & Text 7 & hjhb & hjhbh\\
\hline
Text 2 & Text 4 & Text 6 & Text 8 & hjhb & hjhbh\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

To *not* have `Assay` vertically centered between lines 1 and 2 of the table, it is enough to change `\multirow{2}{*}{Assay}` to `{Assay}` or just to `Assay` in the code.